# Rotation and Setting center of UIView in animation block doesn't work sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

What I want to do is to rotate and bounce my `UIView` simultaneously. So currently, I am using this code in my `UIViewAnimation` block.

```
[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -M_PI*2)];
CGPoint center = CGPointMake( view.center.x - x , view.center.y - y);
[view setCenter:center];
```

And using this, its rotation is happening fine but the view bouncing is not happening i.e not any kind of movement is happening at all. Guidance needed on what I am doing wrong here of if I am missing something.

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout?

Comment: nope. I am not using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use the transform to do both things by applying a rotation and a translation (be careful of the order you apply them in). When you apply a transform to a view you shouldn't then try to change its frame (or center).